# Difference between 'the moon' and 'a moon'?

Tags: vocabulaire

I know we call our moon “la lune,” but what if one is generically referring to “a moon,” such as “a moon of Jupiter”? Is it just “une lune”?

Comment: Du temps des premières découvertes astronomiques, on donnait le nom de *lune* aux satellites des planètes solaires. - Pour Jupiter, les *lunes galiléennes* sont les quatre plus grands des satellites naturels de Jupiter découverts par Galilée : Io, Europe, Ganymède et Callisto.
Cf.: http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lune_galil%C3%A9enne

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, "lune" is also used in French both as the name of Earth's satellite and as a synonym of "satellite".

Comment: A moon isn't a synonym of a satellite as I guess it needs to be telluric or have some specific properties.

Answer (score 8):

I would add that, when referring to *our* moon, the correct writing is:

> la Lune

with an uppercase L. When referring to other moons as regular satellites,

> la lune principale de Jupiter

or

> une lune de Jupiter

would be the correct way to write it.

Comment: L'usage me semble loin d'être universel, je ne suis même pas sur qu'il soit dominant.

Comment: Le fait de mettre une majuscule à un nom propre n'est pas un usage mais une règle d'orthographe, et permet justement de faire la différence entre le nom propre et le substantif (entre autres).

Comment: Le mot « lune » pour désigner le satellite naturel de la terre n'est pas universellement capitalisé, c'est par exemple le cas dans [l'entrée correspondante du dictionnaire de l'Académie française](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/lune) qui précise même _Lune prend la majuscule en astronomie_. (Terre et soleil sont dans le même cas, les astronomes utilisent la majuscule dans leurs textes, l'usage chez le commun des mortels est variable.)